# Wrong RegEx match in Dart

Tags: regex, dart

The code itself: (you can see it on [DartPad](//dartpad.dartlang.org/5c4a07095ecd5b931a34aea291618b21))

```
void main() {
   print(new RegExp("[0-9]|'|\"|\.").hasMatch('g')); // should return false
   print(new RegExp("[0-9]|'|\"|\.").hasMatch('0')); // return correctly true
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
```

With the same version on [regex101](//regex101.com/r/wA8cH2/2) but with JS, the return value is correct.

Is there something I'm missing with my RegExp or should I report a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either you use a raw string

```
print(new RegExp(r'''[0-9]|'|"|\.''').hasMatch('g'));
```

(`'''` is to avoid a conflict with `"` inside the string)

or escape `\`

```
print(new RegExp("[0-9]|'|\"|\\.").hasMatch('g'));
```

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ef2b8cee646ca532f6eee3d08975be62)